# Variable lookup extension in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am looking at some code where some of the variables are really obscure. For example,

```
h582=30
```

where h582 might mean temperature. I have a dictionary that tells me what each variable means. Is there any existing feature or would it be possible to extend visual studio code easily to show me the meaning of each variable on mouse hover?

Comment: That's a ***verrrrry*** specific use case. You are probably gonna have to write it yourself if you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using find/replace on the workspace to rewrite the variables to their readable names (I would go crazy trying to read code like that).

But if you can't do that and want to see the real name when you hover the variable, you could write a vscode extension for this. It would not be too hard - you just need to implement a hover provider which would check the name of the token under the cursor, look it up in the dictionary, and return the result. Example:

```
vscode.languages.registerHoverProvider('javascript', {
    provideHover(document, position, token) {
        const hoveredWord = document.getText(document.getWordRangeAtPosition(position));
        const mappedWord = dictionary[hoveredWord]
        if (mappedWord) {
            return new Hover(mappedWord);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
});
```

See the docs here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_languages